# How to make python lambda return comma operator last one

Tags: javascript, python, lambda, comma-operator

I just want use Javascript [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in python lambda function, and now I know ()[-1] is fit to me.

> Evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

In python

```
# ignore List comprehension
# [ele['val'] for ele in arr ]

from functools import reduce

arr = [{'id': 1, 'val': 100}, {'id': 2, 'val': 200}]
#
# use tuple ()[-1] result [100, 200]
result = reduce(lambda total, ele: (total.append(ele['val']), total)[-1], arr, [])

# use list[][-1] result [100, 200]
result = reduce(lambda total, ele: [total.append(ele['val']), total][-1], arr, [])

result1 = reduce(lambda total, ele: total if total.append(ele['val']) else total, arr, [])
# [100, 200]
```

In Javascript:

```
// ignore map [{'id': 1, 'val': 100}, {'id': 2, 'val': 200}].map(e=>e.val)
[{'id': 1, 'val': 100}, {'id': 2, 'val': 200}].reduce((total, ele) => (total.push(ele.val), total), [])
// [100, 200]
```

Comment: python and javascript have different syntaxes, why do you think they are same? Also what is your expected output and input

Comment: In Javascript, commas do that. In French, "pain" means "bread". That doesn't mean you can ask for pain at the grocery store in the US and expect to get bread, or that you can use a comma in Python and expect to get Javascript behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 if I ask for pain, I expect to get a knuckle sandwich, dammit!

Comment: So, what you really want is a one-line expression which can work in lambda?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is one data type: tuple, which JS does not have.

You can try in Python:

```
a = (1, 2)
# a is (1, 2)
b = 1, 2
# b is also (1, 2), which is tuple
```

and in JS:

```
let a = (1, 2)
// a is 2
let b = 1, 2
// SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

So, in conclusion: both Python and JS have comma operator, but the same operator may not behave in the same way.

The key point is expression such as `(1, 2)` will be evaluated to tuple `(1, 2)` in Python and the last value `2` in JS.

BTW: Python does have comma operator:

> Note that tuples are not formed by the parentheses, but rather by use of the comma operator.

[python reference: parenthesized-forms](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms)

Comment: comma is not an operator in Python

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Python does have comma operator, please see my newest answer.

Comment: You do have a point as it's indeed qualified as "operator" in this part of the doc - but that's really the only place I've ever seen it qualified as such - it doesn't appear in the operator precedence list  nor in the `operator` module.

Comment: But well, if the doc says so, I'm not going to argue ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thx. As for why it didn't appear in the operator precedence list or the operator module, is it possible that it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write Javascript in Python will not really work, better to do it the Pythonic way.

As a general rule, the prefered way to build a list from another (or from any other finite iterable) is to use list comprehension, ie:

```
def test(*args):
    return [a for a in args]
```

but in your cases - where there's no transformation nor filtering - there's an even simpler way: just pass your sequence to the `list` constructor:

```
def test2(*args):
    return list(args)
```